# Onchange event of Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a dropdown list. I am using `onchange` event of this dropdown to show some text in a textbox below.
Its perfectly fine, but I want to to do something like this:---

> If user click on the drop down then the whole list will be populated. right.. Now if he is trying to choose the value from the list using up/down arrow button of the key board I want to fire the event at that time. How can I do this?

`Onchange`  is not working for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function change(value){
      alert("key pressed "+value)
   }    
</script>

<select name="k" onkeypress="change(this.value)">
    <option value="acb">ABC</option>
    <option value="def">DEF</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the onkeydown event. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536938%28VS.85%29.aspx)

In your case, onchange will be raised when the select list loses the focus.